# Stop ViewPager scroll when SwipeRefreshLayout child is triggered

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, swiperefreshlayout

I'm developing a  view with ViewPager2 (horizontal scroll) who handle pages with SwipeRefreshLayout.

My problem is : When I scroll horizontally everything is ok but when I scroll vertically, the SwipeRefreshLayout start to appear and the ViewPager can still scroll horizontally. So that make the usage weird.

I'm looking for disabled the swipe on ViewPager2 when SwipeToRefresh consume the gesture.

Hierarchy of activity with ViewPager

```
<ConstraintLayout >

    <AppBarLayout>
        <MaterialToolbar/>
    <AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar_layout"/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Hierarchy of a page

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView/>
        <LinearLayout/>
        <LinearLayout/>

    </ConstraintLayout>

</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I tried to implement [MultiSwipeRefreshLayout](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/swiperefreshmultipleviews/MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.java) whithout success...

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

It's to wrap the child (in my case ConstraintLayout) of the SwipeRefreshLayout in a NestedScrollView with the parameter `android:fillViewport` at `true`.

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true">

        <ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView/>
            <LinearLayout/>
            <LinearLayout/>

        </ConstraintLayout>

    <NestedScrollView/>

</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Dont know if it's a bad solution but for the moment it work like a charm...